# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a typical Project with Node.js - Express 3 - MongoDB

I'm trying to make a query to my model 'Tweet' in my  /routes/index.js and when I run my app crashed

```
24 Aug 11:35:07 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ocesa/fanocesa/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:286
  throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
        ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Teewt".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
at Mongoose.model (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ocesa/fanocesa/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:286:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ocesa/fanocesa/routes/index.js:6:33)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ocesa/fanocesa/app.js:7:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
24 Aug 11:35:07 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is part of my app.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/fanOcesa');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectID = Schema.ObjectID;

var Teewt = new Schema({
    cuerpo: String
});

var Teewt = mongoose.model('Teewt', Teewt);

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

And this is part of my index.js

```
var Teewt = require('mongoose').model('Teewt');

Teewt.find({}, function(err, docs){
    console.log('docs');
    console.log(docs);
});

exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { 
        docs: docs
    });
};
```

which would be the correct way to do this query?

Comment: You don't show where you're calling `require` to bring `index.js` into `app.js`, but if that's before you register the schema with the `mongoose.model` call, then that's your problem.

Comment: File / routes / index.js express calls automatically, if I'm not wrong is in this line

 `app.get ('/', routes.index);`

That is after the register the schema as you can see in the code of app.js

Comment: It's not called automatically, it's this line in the generated app.js code: `var routes = require('./routes');`

Comment: Thast It, thanks JohnnyHK +1

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `index.js` file is executed where your `app.js` file calls:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
```

So be sure that's being called *after* your calls to register the `'Teewt'` schema as a mongoose model in `app.js`.

Comment: How to implement your concept for dynamically created schema model?

Answer (score 1):

Name your schema and model differently. Re-declaring `Teewt` is a javascript "bad part" as well as a mistake in any programming language. Just call the schema `TeewtSchema` and the model `Teewt` (since the schema is typically only used in 1 file in an application, but the model may be used extensively).

Comment: You're right it is bad practice and change the name of the varible, but does not solve the error

index.js apparently runs first that register the schema

Comment: Yes, indeed JohnnyHK's comment is probably your root cause.

Comment: It's also not clear that you understand his comment. Find the line in `app.js` that does `var routes = require('routes');` and move it lower in the file so it comes AFTER your mongoose model is configured.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too. Was baffled for long, following this and similar threads for help, trying to debug. Ultimately the issue turned out to be due to mongoose version in my case. I was trying to use mongoose-fixture to seed some default data to start with into mongo.

Try this: delete the `node_modules` dir of your project, run an `npm cache clean`, and then an `npm install`. If even this doesn't help, try comparing versions of `mongoose` / `mongoose-fixture` between the problematic app and one that works, and try changing the version in your `package.json`, and repeating the above steps. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in other words, this line (from app.js):

```
var Teewt = mongoose.model('Teewt', Teewt);
```

should be called after the Tweet was registered, on that line (in index.js):

```
var Teewt = require('mongoose').model('Teewt');
```